# How do i show a list in a javascript array from a php code using a html input field?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to achieve a autocomplete html input field that gets a list of names from sql database that should be populated once clicking in the input field. I've came across a javascript autocomplete code that uses its own array but i wanted to populate its array with the sql array list instead. Would the below code work?

```
  <div class="autocomplete">
  <input type="text" name="customer" id="myInput" placeholder="Search Customers" value="<?php echo $CustomerSet['id']; ?>"> 
  </div>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var a, b, i, val = this.value;

  closeAllLists();
  if (!val) { return false;}
  currentFocus = -1;

  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

  this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

      b = document.createElement("DIV");

      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

          closeAllLists();
      });
      a.appendChild(b);
    }
  }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {

    currentFocus++;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up

    currentFocus--;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentFocus > -1) {

      if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
    }
  }
  });
  function addActive(x) {

if (!x) return false;

removeActive(x);
if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
 }
 }
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
}
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  closeAllLists(e.target);
 });
}

var customers = ["<?php

                    foreach( $this->fetchCustomers[2] as $CustomerSet ) :

                        echo '<option value="'. $CustomerSet['id'] .'" ';

                        if ( $_POST['customer'] == $CustomerSet['id'] ) :

                            echo ' SELECTED ';

                        endif;

                        echo '>'. $CustomerSet['id'] .' - '. strtoupper(     $CustomerSet['customer_first'] .'  '. $CustomerSet['customer_last'] ) .'</option>';

                    endforeach;
                ?>"];
   autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), customers);
   </script>
```

Comment: Need some clarification or details on what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to take a hash or list in php and print it in a format that would be interpreted as an array in javascript?  This may be accomplished using json_encode or a simple loop.

Comment: Yes, im trying to take a php list and print it in the javascript array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the perfect solution using jquery which seem to have been used by someone else here on stackoverflow. My solution i used was https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and all i did was made minor changes to my php/html form code. This helped me in a major way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the options was formed as a single string.  Try rebuilding the results in php to a simple array then using join to list in a simple array.

```
  <div class="autocomplete">
  <input type="text" name="customer" id="myInput" placeholder="Search Customers" value="<?php echo $CustomerSet['id']; ?>"> 
  </div>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var a, b, i, val = this.value;

  closeAllLists();
  if (!val) { return false;}
  currentFocus = -1;

  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

  this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

      b = document.createElement("DIV");

      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

          closeAllLists();
      });
      a.appendChild(b);
    }
  }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {

    currentFocus++;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up

    currentFocus--;

    addActive(x);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentFocus > -1) {

      if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
    }
  }
  });
  function addActive(x) {

if (!x) return false;

removeActive(x);
if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
 }
 }
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
}
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  closeAllLists(e.target);
 });
}
<?php
$customers = array();
foreach( $this->fetchCustomers[2] as $CustomerSet ) {
    $selected = $_POST['customer'] == $CustomerSet['id'] ? 'SELECTED':'';
    $customers[] = '"<option value=\''. addslashes($CustomerSet['id']) .'\' ' . $selected . '>'. addslashes($CustomerSet['id']) .' - '. addslashes(strtoupper($CustomerSet['customer_first'])) .'  '. addslashes($CustomerSet['customer_last']) .'</option>"';
}
?>
var customers = [<?php echo join(',', $customers) ?>];
   autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), customers);
   </script>
```

Comment: There is no list being displayed

Comment: Do i need to take the php code from out the var array and display this on the same page with the json code?

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected php output is.  FRom the code it looks like it will be something like: `var customers = ["<option value="1">1 - NAME</option><option value="2">2 - NAME</option>"];`  which is unlikely to work as expected.  If you are trying to generate a list of strings where each string represents an option element I can update the example in my answer.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes each string would represent an option within the array

Comment: or do i need to add that array code as the html form Value="" by using php echo?

Comment: Sorry, didn't test.  I had an extra close paran and messed up the customers variable name in php. Try again please.

Comment: Im a little confused about the coding and where it goes. I know where im supposed to place the var customer coding..but does the code above the var get inserted into the java code also?

Comment: Seems like post this code grabs only just one name from the list of 8 customers which seems close but still far, what maybe missing?  `var customers = ["<?php echo strtoupper($CustomerSet['customer_first'] .'  '. $CustomerSet['customer_last'] ); ?>"];`